# How to push a button down in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I am working hours on this drop-down menu that I could not really seem to work. Whenever I try to add submenu, the submenu items push the Products button up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Dik İşleme, CNC, Talaşlı İmalat">
    <meta name="author" content="Aras">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" id="logo"> 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Anasayfa - Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda - About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ürünler - Products</a>
                    <ul id="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Ürün 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">İletişim</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And then

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo{
    height: 8%;
    width: 8%;
}

div nav{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1; /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1; /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul li{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1; /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul li a{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.5px;
}

div nav ul li a:hover{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #9f7934;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

div nav ul li a:hover{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #9f7934;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#dropdown{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I have tried using absolute positioning for submenu but that did not seem like it works as expected.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZWprN

Is there any way to eliminate submenu from pushing the products button up? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here for an improved version: https://codepen.io/DavidDeprost/pen/gZWawg?editors=1100

Most important changes:

```
#logo {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

div nav ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1; 
    position: relative;
}

#dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

- Change the size of the logo from 8% to 70px, so it is always taller than the navbar
- Add `position: relative;` to `div nav ul li` to allow its child `#dropdown` to be positioned relative to it.
- Some additions to `#dropdown`, to position it relative to its parent, `div nav ul li`

Comment: Thank you for the answer David Deprost :)